# Debug ASP.NET MVC application after it is moved to production

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I have a application with Facebook login implemented and it is working fine on my local machine.

As soon as I have moved it to production, FB login stopped working.

I have spent a lot of time figuring out what the problem could be but unable to find the solution.

Is there anyway I can debug my application on production server? Or any other way I can test it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's a way to debug application on production server.

**1. Copy the corresponding "Remote Debugger" Folder (x86 or x64) to your production server.** (You can find the folder under Visual Studio Tools/Remote Debug Folder[image]

**2. Run msvsmon.exe in the Production Server**
[image]

**3. Uncheck "Enable Just My Code"** in your Visual Studio
[image]

**4. "Attach to Process" and Select "Qualifier" to point to your production server**
[image]

After all these steps, you'd be able to Debug the application as you like.

Comment: One thing I didn't mentioned is I am usign Shared Hosting. So I do not have RDP access to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't debug your application on server. As workaround you can add logging. As logging engines you can use [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) or some kind of [logger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.logger.aspx) or even write to file.